# elasticsearch index mappings are not updating

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I'm trying to update the mappings of an elasticsearch index.
The current mappings of one of the properties in my ES index is.

```
`"mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

I would like to update the above mappings and add 'normalizer' in fields keyword and 'phonetic' in the fields object. What is the right way to update/modify the existing mapings of an index to look like this. i'm adding this normalizer for sorting purpose.

```
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256,
                    "normalizer": "keyword_lowercase"
                },
                "phonetic": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "phonetic_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this index is part of a data stream, please refer to the [data stream documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modify-data-streams.html#data-streams-change-mappings-and-settings).

If this is a standalone index, it is not possible to change normalizer for an existing field since it will conflict with already indexed data. You need to delete the index and create a new one with desired settings and mappings. If the data is not available anywhere else, you can [reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) it into a new index with desired settings and mappings.

You can add the `name.phonetic` subfield to existing index, but it will not be available in the documents that are not already index. If the phonetic_analyzer is not defined. You need to [close the index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.9/indices-close.html), [update settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.9/indices-update-settings.html) to define the analyzer and [open the index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.9/indices-open-close.html). After that you can [update mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.9/indices-put-mapping.html).